# Left outer join on bizarre data model in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I've got a class that looks like this:

```
public class KpiValue
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string NAME { get; set; }

    public string ORG_UNIT_ID { get; set; }

    public string SITE_ID { get; set; }

    public string AREA_ID { get; set; }

    public double? VALUE { get; set; }

}
```

And corresponding `Site`, `Area`, `Organization` and `OrgUnit` classes, each with an ID property. Only one of the properties will have a value, the rest will be null (not my idea).

I'd like to normalize this structure into something useful, assigning a NAME property that looks like:

"Area: My First Area" or
"Site: Best Site Ever"

That consists of the NAME of the site or area or org, etc that matches the corresponding ID property (AREA_ID or SITE_ID or...) of my class.

Assuming I've got this so far...

```
var org = Organization.FindByProperty("NAME",orgName);

var orgUnits = org.GetOrgUnits().AsEnumerable();

var sites = from OrgUnit ou in orgUnits
            from Site s in ou.GetSites()
            select s;

var areas = from Site s in sites
            from area in s.Areas()
            select area;

//help!
var monthlyGrid = from KpiValue monthlyKpi in kpiMonthlyValues
                  join area in areas on monthlyKpi.AREA_ID equals area.ID
                  join site in sites on monthlyKpi.SITE_ID equals site.ID
                  join orgUnit in orgUnits on monthlyKpi.ORG_UNIT_ID equals orgUnit.ID
                  select new monthlyKpi()
                  {
                   NAME = //"Area: MyArea" or "Site: MySite"
                   ...
                   };
```

The join seems to be matching with AND conditions, not OR conditions... How can I achieve this in LINQ?

Comment: So you're saying you want to take each `KpiValue` and "convert" them into strings as you've described?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Left outer join example on the [Linq 101](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin) site.

You need to use [`Enumrable.DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx).